# Google link scrapping with python does not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to take all founded url's that founded by googles like [www.wikipedia.com/..](http://www.wikipedia.com/..). but my code is not working list is always empty

Google stores links in class yuRUbf so i wrote like this

**Here is my code:
**

```
import requests
import bs4


searchkey = "behzat ç oyuncuları"
print(searchkey)

if " " in searchkey:
    searchkey = searchkey.split(" ")
    searchkey= "%20".join(searchkey)

print("Googling...")




r = requests.get(r"https://www.google.com/search?q="+searchkey)

soap = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

lists = soap.select(".yuRUbf a")
print(lists)
for i in range(len(lists)):
    print(lists[i].get("href"))
```

Thank you...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set `Uset-Agent` HTTP header to get correct page from the Google's servers (also, don't add `%20` to the URL parameters, `requests` do this automatically):

```py
import bs4
import requests

searchkey = "behzat ç oyuncuları"
print(searchkey)

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0"
}

params = {
    "q": searchkey,  # <-- your search key
    "hl": "en",  # <-- show only english results
}

print("Googling...")

r = requests.get(r"https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
soap = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

wikipedia_links = [
    a.get("href") for a in soap.select(".yuRUbf a") if "wikipedia" in a.get("href", "")
]
print(*wikipedia_links, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
behzat ç oyuncuları
Googling...
https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behzat_%C3%87._Bir_Ankara_Polisiyesi_karakterleri_listesi
https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=tr&u=https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behzat_%25C3%2587._Bir_Ankara_Polisiyesi_karakterleri_listesi&prev=search&pto=aue
```